# Creating macros in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, module

I have just opened a new workbook and saved in xlms format. I then went into developer and into the visual basic pane and typed in a macro which was automatically saved in Module 1. I had no problem running the macro from the visual basic pane. However, when I looked at the Macro pane, although I could see the new macro I had just created in the list, all the buttons except "create" were grayed out. Pressing "create" seemingly created a blank macro in Module 2, but I was unable to either edit or run the macro from there. This is in contrast to my previous experience; other older projects continue to work in the expected way with all available macros listed in the macro pane from where they can be edited or run. It seems as if something in the VBA environment has gone wrong. Any ideas? Thanks.

Here is offending subroutine, but this is not the only one I have tried to enter

```
Sub C02_open_new_worksheet()

yearto = Cells(2, 1).Value
lengthyear = Cells(2, 6).Value
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("longtable")).Name = "Year_to_" & yearto
 
'Copy from longtable into new column positions in crosstable

For numrow = 2 To lengthyear + 1
    Cells(numrow, 1) = Sheets("longtable").Cells(numrow, 3).Value
    Cells(numrow, 2) = Sheets("longtable").Cells(numrow, 2).Value
    Cells(numrow, 3) = Sheets("longtable").Cells(numrow, 4).Value
Next numrow
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you make a subroutine or a function? Functions can't be called from the macro screen, nor can parameterized subs.

Comment: subroutines  without parameters only

Comment: Maybe you can include the code for the subroutine you are trying to run in your question?

Comment: If I enter the code above into Excel I can see it in the Macro pane.

Comment: I don't doubt that things are working fine for everybody else and I am confident that it is nothing to do with my code. What I am asking is what is wrong with my system that it produces the effect described?